# Encrypt file with Ruby OpenSSL and decrypt with command line

Tags: ruby, openssl

I am automating an OpenSSL file encryption process using Ruby. The files encrypted this way need to be able to be decrypted using OpenSSL on linux command line.

I can encrypt the file using the following Ruby method:

```
  def encrypt_file
    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
    cipher.encrypt
    cipher.key = "somelongkeystring"

    buf = ""
    File.open("file.enc", "wb") do |outf|
      File.open("file.zip", "rb") do |inf|

        while inf.read(4096, buf)
          outf << cipher.update(buf)
        end
        outf << cipher.final
      end
    end
  end
```

I need to be able to decrypt the file (file.enc) using the following command:

```
$ openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in file.enc -out file.zip
```

However, when I run this I get an error for `bad magic number` after I type the key from above.

Since I cannot change the decrypt approach (meaning it uses only a password and is entered on linux command line) how can I change my Ruby method to encrypt the file so it can be decrypted this way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602069/why-cant-i-make-openssl-with-ruby-and-command-line-openssl-interoperable

Comment: @MarcoSandrini my question is similar to that question. however, the solution given was to change the openssl command which I stated I cannot do. I can only modify the Ruby method.

Comment: Then you should change your code so that it would use the same derivation algorithms that the command-line version of openssl uses to derivate key and IV from the passphrase. But quoting the answer of question http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29106/openssl-recover-key-and-iv-by-passphrase  "uses a custom key derivation function with some repeated hashing. This is a non-standard and not-well vetted construct (!) which relies on the MD5 hash function of dubious reputation (!!);"

Comment: Given the info in the answer quoted in my previous comment, I would start thinking about alternative routes, like wrapping an invocation to the openssl command line tool into a system/exec/spawn call

Comment: @MarcoSandrini calling openssl from system or exec or open3 only accepts input from keyboard or tty. It does not accept stdin for providing the key.

Comment: looking at the OpenSSL manual, as one of the options for the pass phrase arguments it specifies `-pass stdin`.  If that doesn't work, I would try with `-pass file:my_named_pipe` and use a named pipe.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of a similar question in stackoverflow, Im able to achieve it in ruby.

First u've to add an `iv` thing into ur cipher object, like this

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
cipher.encrypt
cipher.iv = "0"*16
cipher.key = "somelongkeystring"
```

While decryption u've to pass `-K` and `-iv` values

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in file.enc -out file.zip -K <key_hex_code> -iv <iv_hex_code>
```

U can generate `hex` codes in ruby like this `"string".unpack('H*')`. There must be some way to generate hex codes in cli as well.

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on Sumit's answer:

```
require 'openssl'

class Crypto
  def initialize(key, iv, data, cipher='aes-256-cbc')
    @key = key 
    @iv = iv
    @cipher = cipher
    @data = data
  end 

  def encrypt
    c = OpenSSL::Cipher.new(@cipher).encrypt
    c.iv = @iv 
    c.key = @key
    c.update(@data) + c.final    
  end 

  def decrypt
    c = OpenSSL::Cipher.new(@cipher).decrypt
    c.iv = @iv 
    c.key = @key
    c.update(@data) + c.final    
  end 
end

iv = '0'*16
key = '1'*32
message = 'My Message' 
encrypted = Crypto.new(key,iv,message).encrypt
puts Crypto.new(key,iv,encrypted).decrypt
puts `echo -n '#{encrypted}' | openssl aes-256-cbc -d -K #{key.unpack('H*').first} -iv #{iv.unpack('H*').first}`
# My Message
# My Message
```

This solutions works for strings, can easily be adapted to files.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work though not using the Ruby OpenSSL implementation (which I would prefer). If you use the -k flag you can specify a password as the next argument then you don't need to pass anything and can use system to call it.

```
  system("openssl aes-256-cbc -k '#{key}' -in file.zip -out file.enc")
```

If anyone has an approach using the Ruby OpenSSL implementation I would appreciate it.